# How to include PNG (or PDF) and EPS Files in LaTeX (Overleaf)?

Tags: pdf, eps, overleaf, png

I need to include both types of these files in my document (and definitely need EPS as I'm importing organic mechanisms), but I can't seem to find anything that works.

As such, I'm on the setting LaTeX compiler rather than pdfLaTeX, as eps files did not work on that.

Thanks!

Comment: A current pdflatex can handle eps, it converts it on the fly to pdf, but you can also use epstopdf to do the conversion yourself if overleaf can't do it.

Comment: So I tried this but then basically chemnum (which numbers chemical compounds throughout) didn't work, so basically I definitely need latex and not pdflatex

Comment: do you know how I use dvips on Overleaf?

Comment: @EliNathan if you are using latex then you will be (but it doesn't support png, I misled you, sorry) you need to convert both pdf and png to eps in that case

Comment: Recent versions of pdflatex will auto-convert file.eps to file-eps-converted-to.pdf and then embed that pdf file in the document. It's a smart conversion; i.e., it won't convert it again unless file.eps has been updated. Also, pdflatex will include png by default.